# How to specify where clause with at least x values from nested select

Tags: sqlite, relational-division

Suppose I have these tables:

**person**

```
id  name
--  ----
1   dude
2   john
3   doe
...etc
```

**favourite_food**

```
personid   food
--------  ------
    1     apples
    5     apples
    5     oranges
```

And I want to get a list of the names of people who like at least the foods that person 5 likes. Something like below:

```
SELECT p.name FROM person p
LEFT JOIN favourite_food ff ON ff.personid = p.id
WHERE ff.food = (SELECT food FROM favourite_food WHERE personid = 5)
AND ff.personid <> 5;
```

Except I have no idea how to specify the 'at least' part. Do I have to create a temporary table or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL essentially works with sets, so it often helps to reformulate your problem strictly in terms of set theory.

"At least" could be reformulated this way:
If we look only at foods that are favourite foods of person 5, which persons have the same number of favourite foods as person 5?

```
SELECT name
FROM person
WHERE id IN (SELECT personid
             FROM favourite_food
             WHERE food IN (SELECT food
                            FROM favourite_food
                            WHERE personid = 5)
             GROUP BY personid
             HAVING COUNT(food) = (SELECT COUNT(food)
                                   FROM favourite_food
                                   WHERE personid = 5)
            )
```

Alternatively, use this reformulation:
We do *not* want persons who do not like a food that person 5 likes.
Therefore, find all persons for which no food exists that is liked by person 5 but not liked by that person:

```
SELECT name
FROM person
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM favourite_food AS person5_food
                  WHERE personid = 5
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM favourite_food
                                    WHERE personid = person.id
                                      AND food = person5_food.food)
                 )
```

---

(Actually, SQL is based on the [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), and the operation you want is called *division*.)